# How do I require that a generic type supports numeric operations?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a struct (and some methods) like this:

```
pub struct Foo<T> where T:Ord+Add+Sub {
    bar: T,
    baz: T,
    // ...
}
```

I need to do some numeric operations (addition, subtraction etc) and store the results. The documentation states that the result in the `Sub` or `Add` traits may be yet another type.

Comment: You can use the `Num` trait of the num crate if other solutions become too verbose for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [the `Add` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) you will see:

```
pub trait Add<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

This is the flexibility required to specify the result type depending on both the Left and Right arguments to `+`.

If you wish to constrain your `Foo<T>` structure to `T` for which there exists a symmetric implementation of `T` which itself returns `T`, you can do so in the `where` clause:

- to require that `T` can be added to `T`, `T` must implement `Add<T>` (which, since `RHS` defaults to `Self`, is the same as implementing `Add`)
- to require that the result be `T`, `T` must implement `Add<Output = T>` (the associated type syntax)

A similar principle applies to `Sub`, giving:

```
struct Foo<T>
    where T: Ord + Add<Output = T> + Sub<Output = T>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but as delnan points out, there's nothing *numeric* about `T` (and there probably shouldn't be). This simply allows any type that can be added to its own type and produce its own type.

Comment: Oh certainly, for example, it would make sense for matrices even though they are not the first thing that pops to mind when thinking numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "numeric type", but this is how you constrain the type such that addition and subtraction yield `T`:

```
pub struct Foo<T> where T: Ord+Add<Output=T>+Sub<Output=T> {
    ...
}
```